# Finding arc length parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find an arc length parameterization for $r(t)= (e^t\sin(t), e^t\cos(t), 8e^t)$.

Tried to follow normal steps and got $t=\ln(s/\sqrt{66})$. Not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 2):

Let $r(t)=(e^t\sin(t), e^t\cos(t), 8e^t)$. Then $r'(t)=(e^t\sin(t)+e^t\cos(t),e^t\cos(t)-e^t\sin(t),8e^t)$ and $$|r'(t)|=\sqrt{(e^t\sin(t)+e^t\cos(t))^2+(e^t\cos(t)-e^t\sin(t))^2+64e^2t}=\sqrt{66}e^{t}$$

You first computed the legth $s=s(t)$ as a function of $t$

$$s(t)=\int_{0}^{t}|r'(x)|dx=\sqrt{66}e^t|_{0}^{t}=\sqrt{66}e^t-\sqrt{66}$$

Now we need to invert to get $t=t(s)=\ln\left(\frac{s+\sqrt{66}}{\sqrt{66}}\right)$

Comment: Perfectly the lower limit can be $-\infty$ and it simplifies a little.